# A question with Jordan measurable

Tags: analysis

$\textbf{Definition :}$ A set $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan measurable if exists $R$ a rectangle such that $A\subseteq R$ and the function $\chi_{A} : R \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.

Consider $Y\subseteq X$ where $X,Y$ are Jordan measurable. So exists a rectangle $R$ such that $X\subseteq R$ and $\chi_{X}$ is integrable. Then $\chi_{Y}$ is integrable?. 
Or equivalently : if $X$ is Jordan measurable then for all $R$ rectangle such that $X\subseteq R$ we have that $\chi_{X}$ is integrable?.

Intuitively, I would say yes, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Surely you mean that $\chi_A$ is *Riemann* integrable?

Comment: Yes is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and it can be proved using Lemma 13.1 in Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres.

> **If $f$ is a bounded function that vanishes outside of $R\cap R'$ where $R,R'$ are rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\int_R f =
>  \int_{R'} f$, where one integral exists if and only if the other
>   does.**

In this case, take $f = \chi_X$ and let $R$ and $R'$ be any rectangles such that $X \subset R$ and $X \subset R'$. Since $X \subset R \cap R'$ it follows that $\int_R \chi_X = \int_{R'} \chi_X$.